# PyQT - setting the text color for a QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

Is there any way to set the text color of a certain tab that's part of a QTabWidget? [QTabBar](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtabbar.html#setTabTextColor) seems to have a method to set the tab text color, but I do not see a similar method for [QTabWidget.](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtabwidget.html#setTabText)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tab text color can be set via the tab-widget's [tabBar](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qtabwidget.html#tabBar) method:

```
tabwidget.tabBar().setTabTextColor(index, color)
```

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't checked the site for a while and didn't see your answer.  Thanks!