# QTabBar.setTabTextColor not working, or improper usage?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, pyside

having some trouble setting the color of the text in a QTabWidget. Wondering what I might be doing wrong here.

No luck per the example sited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170638/pyqt-setting-the-text-color-for-a-qtabwidget/9177189#9177189)

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

# QTabWidget
tab_widget = QTabWidget()
tab_a = QWidget()
tab_b = QWidget()
tab_widget.addTab(tab_a, 'tab_a')
tab_widget.addTab(tab_b, 'tab_b')
tab_widget.tabBar().setTabTextColor(0,Qt.red)
tab_widget.show()
```

The resulting text in the tabBar is just the standard white/gray.

Some other entries suggest subclassing QTabWidget may be necessary. 
Method number 2 shows a custom tab widget

```
# CUSTOM Tab Widget
class MyTabWidget(QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTabWidget,self).__init__()

    def setTabTextColor(self, ind, color):
        self.tabBar().setTabTextColor(ind, color)

tab_widget = MyTabWidget()
tab_a = QWidget()
tab_b = QWidget()
tab_widget.addTab(tab_a, 'tab_a')
tab_widget.addTab(tab_b, 'tab_b')
tab_widget.setTabTextColor(0,Qt.red)
tab_widget.show()
```

In both cases, my tab text color remains the default white/gray. Querying the color appears to show a change, but the visible color is still white/gray.

```
tab_widget.tabTextColor(0)
# Result: PySide.QtGui.QColor.fromRgbF(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000) #
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried it and your code works fine. You could tell us the version of pyside and python

Comment: Looks like PySide.__version__ == 1.2.0

and sys.version == 2.7.6

Comment: I have used the following versions: PySide 1.2.4, python 2.7.13 and 3.6.2 in linux. whats is your OS?

Comment: Linux. kde_rhel7

Comment: I use Arch linux. How did you install pyside, from the repositories or did you use pip?

Comment: I'm working within a fairly managed software ecosystem so I don't install anything myself, unfortunately.

This particular version of PySide was distributed with the application maya 2016.5.

Comment: I think it is a bug in the version you have installed or in the form of installation, I guess the system you do have support, I would recommend consulting, because your code is correct.

Comment: Cool, thanks so much for double checking for me!

Comment: I have same problem in maya 2019 with pyside2